# How to apply JavaScript to an array of text-boxes with different IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

In addition to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083403/extracting-input-from-all-input-boxes-into-a-list-using-flask); Thank you to Mr. Arsho for providing such explainable answer. In HTML (or with flask) I have following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def search():
    students = ['Mr. A', 'Mr. B', 'Mr. C']
    return render_template('dynamic_input.html', students = students)

@app.route('/results', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('/'))
    else:
        # I can handle this here...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The HTML template is as follow of index:

```
<!-- dynamic_input.html -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Give the grades</h1>
  <form action="/results" method="post">
    {% for s in students %} 
    <div>
       {{ s }}:
         <input type="text" value="Quiz1" name="quiz1[]">
         <input type="text" value="Quiz2" name="quiz2[]">
         <input type="text" value="Quiz3" name="quiz3[]">
         <input type="text" value="Total" name="total[]">
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
  </form>
</div>
```

Can we write a JavaScript which will add quiz1-quiz4 and show the total in total. I can do it if the text boxes are fixed here it is dynamics, so I need help of the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template you can apply `onchange` event of JavaScript to get the values of each textboxes when it is changed.Then you can add this value to total marks of the same student.

Additionally,
I have updated the Python code to use `Dictionary` rather than `List` of student names. It uses `request.form.getlist()` method to get each student's marks as a list. This list contains 3 quiz marks and the total mark of each student.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def search():
    students = {1: 'Mr. A', 2: 'Mr. B', 3: 'Mr. C'}
    return render_template('dynamic_input.html', students = students)

@app.route('/results', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('search'))
    else:
        data = []
        for student in request.form:
            data.append(request.form.getlist(student))
        return jsonify(data)
```

`dynamic_input.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dynamic calculation using JS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Give the grades</h1>
    <form action="/results" method="post">
      {% for student_id, student_name in students.items() %}
      <div class="student_wrapper">
        {{ student_name }}:
        <input type="text" onchange="update_marks(this);" placeholder="Enter Quiz 1 marks of {{ student_name }}" name="students_{{ student_id }}_marks" id="quiz_1_{{ student_id }}">
        <input type="text" onchange="update_marks(this);" placeholder="Enter Quiz 2 marks of {{ student_name }}" name="students_{{ student_id }}_marks" id="quiz_2_{{ student_id }}">
        <input type="text" onchange="update_marks(this);" placeholder="Enter Quiz 3 marks of {{ student_name }}" name="students_{{ student_id }}_marks" id="quiz_3_{{ student_id }}">
        <input type="text" class="total_marks" value="0" placeholder="Total marks of {{ student_name }}" name="students_{{ student_id }}_marks">
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    function update_marks(current_element){
      var student_element = current_element.closest(".student_wrapper");
      var total_marks_element = student_element.querySelector(".total_marks");
      total_marks_element.value=parseInt(total_marks_element.value)+parseInt(current_element.value);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the marks can be floating number use `parseFloat` function rather than `parseInt`.

**Figure 1:** Before submitting the form the total mark is updated in onchange event of the quiz mark.

[image: before submission]

**Figure 2:** After submitting the form values are parsed into list where the last items is the total marks.

[image: after submission]

Comment: Thank you, dear. Really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: @JunaidBaber, upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array and map the input field, for the example:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

{ array.map((id) => <input type="number" value={"quiz-" + id} id={"quiz-" + id}>) }
```

Then somewhere:

```
function getTotal(array) {
  var i = 0, total = 0, el;
  while (i < array.length) {
    el = document.getElementById('quiz-' + array[i++]);
    if (el) total += parseInt(el.value) | 0;
  }
  return total;
}
```

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to JS solution, you can use a `dict` instead `list` for students.

```
// python
students = {1: 'Mr. A', 2: 'Mr. B', 3: 'Mr. C'}

// html
{% for id, name in students.items() %}
<div>
   {{ name }}:
     <input type="text" value="Quiz1" name="quiz-{{ id }}[]" id="quiz-{{ id }}">
     <input type="text" value="Quiz2" name="quiz-{{ id }}[]" id="quiz-{{ id }}">
     <input type="text" value="Quiz3" name="quiz-{{ id }}[]" id="quiz-{{ id }}">
     <input type="text" value="Total" name="total-{{ id }}[]" id="quiz-total-{{ id }}">
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```